# fscanf for multiple values - can't make it work

Tags: scanf

I can't figure the proper style to write multiple "%...." to work.  I'm reading from a file formatted as blocks of digits separated with comma `,` like:

```
913,91,011,3
391,391
04,111

940,1,999
```

It can be 1 to 3 digits and comma is only in-between numbers on the same line... it could also be nothing. I tried to read each line like this:

```
res=fscanf(users,"%[^,\n]c%c",lockid,&temp2);
```

Which supposed to bring me

```
lockid=913 (its char*)
temp2=',' or '\n' (its char)
and res=2 (int)
```

But I got `lockid=913` and `temp2` didn't change at all (remained unknown) and `res = 1`.

If I separated it to:

```
res1=fscanf(users,"%[^,\n]3s",lockid);
res2=fscanf(users,"%c",temp1);
```

I got what I wanted but it took me 2 lines... why doesn't it work?
It happened with all of my `fscanf`s. Could you please tell me what is the right way to write it? My teacher said there should be nothing in between each `%`
I saw on the internet people use space in between, so I tried that too, but still nothing.
I also tried to do `fscanf(fp,"%d""%d",num1,num2)` but the same error: `num2` doesn't collect the second `%d`...

Could it be the way it compiled or something?
I'm using Visual Studio latest edition and version writing in C.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to read the integer and the character that separates them. Am I correct?

Answer (score 0):

I tried

```
int num;
char separaotor;
fscanf(fp, "%d%c", &num, &separator);
```

and I got

> num = 913
>   separator = ,

Is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I need it as `%s`
   
\n

`044` and `44` is not the same number in my case.

Comment: Would it work if you read it as %d and then convert the result to string?